# General way to set JVM args in pom.xml independent from plugin used

Tags: maven, xslt, maven-plugin, maven-mojo

I have a Maven project which generates code with the help of the `org.codehaus.mojo.xml-maven-plugin` (version 1.0.2) by using XSLT transformation.

However, when run it exceeds the XPath operator limit of 100:

```
JAXP0801002: the compiler encountered an XPath expression containing '101' operators that exceeds the '100' limit set by 'FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING'.
```

I know I can get around this by setting `-Djdk.xml.xpathExprOpLimit=500` on the command line. But is there a way to set this in a general place in the pom.xml?

I know that some plugins like surefire have this possibility. But what about plugins that don't? Is there a way to achieve this in the POM without having to specify it on the command line on each run?

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Java version: 11.0.19, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
```

The full POM file could be found here: https://github.com/david-gibbs-ig/quickfixj/blob/9eff0b69f90ef205ace736bc7fa32784fe3185f3/quickfixj-base/pom.xml#L75

Relevant section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
        <id>extractRequiredFields</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>transform</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <transformationSets>
                <transformationSet>
                    <dir>${project.basedir}/../quickfixj-orchestration/target/generated-resources</dir>
                    <outputDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-resources/extracted</outputDir>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${orchestra.file}</include>
                    </includes>
                    <stylesheet>${project.basedir}/src/main/xsl/extractRequiredFields.xsl</stylesheet>
                </transformationSet>
            </transformationSets>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Does your plugin spin up an extra JVM or does it run in the same JVM as the Maven build itself?

Comment: Can you mentioned the exact plugin ... have you checked the docs of the plugin?

Comment: Good question @JFabianMeier. How can I find out? Didn't find anything related on https://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/

Comment: Please give the exact coordinates of the plugin which means groupId, artifactId and version of the pluginn best would be also to post the full pom file... jdk version, maven version etc..

Comment: @khmarbaise question updated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I was asking for in the original question, but I have now achieved a similar thing by setting the desired options in the `.mvn/jvm.config` file. The file is checked into the repo and retrieved on checkout so Maven considers the file without needing changes to the environment of the user.